# Travel worldwide with car, car insurance?

Tags: insurance

How do worldwide travelers with own car go around insurance policies of their domicile country where car is registered? In my country, in order to renew your car registration I need to show up for technical check, pay insurance etc. How the people deal with this? Do they pay insurance for every border they cross or what? Thanks :)

Comment: If you're planning to drive around the world, bear in mind that you may have issues beyond just insurance, especially once you get out of Europe or North America. China, for instance, doesn't allow anyone without a Chinese license to drive, while a few countries (such as Egypt) require an (expensive) Carnet de Passage to temporarily import a car.

Comment: A non-Chinese friend just a few months ago drove through China from Mongolia to Thailand and, so, it is possible to drive there without a Chinese license. Actually, she drove on a French license from France to China by the north and the is going back, currently in Iran, by the south, all with the one French license. I have no idea about insurance but I will ask now that this question made me curious.

Answer (score 1):

Many countries accept use of your own country's insurance/road tax/etc for temporary visits. This is heavily dependent on where your car is insured, and where you are visiting, so you will have to actually contact the relevant authorities in most countries you intend to cross.

With my UK car insurance and licence, I am currently okay to drive across most of Europe, and some other countries, but if I were to drive across to China, for example, there would be numerous countries along the way I would need to arrange temporary insurance for.

I **probably** wouldn't need to have the car assessed in most countries, but they will want to see my UK insurance documentation, and possibly roadworthiness certification.